# Hyperref form with RTL main language like Arabic

Tags: hyperref, arabic, right-to-left, forms, bidi

I would like to typeset an electronic form with Arabic as the main language and English as another language in the same document. I used the `xetex` engine without success, the layout was messy as you see in the below MWE:

**MWE code**

```
\documentclass[a4,pagesize=pdftex,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=mashriq,numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}
% User-defined commands
\newcommand{\AR}{\textarabic}
\newcommand{\EN}{\textenglish}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\centering
 \LARGE\textbf{استمارة باللغة العربية}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vskip 1cm

\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,maxlen=30,width=0.5\textwidth]{اسم الوثيقة:} 

\TextField[mappingname=title,name=title,backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,width=0.5\textwidth,multiline]{تعليق:}

 \LARGE\textbf{نوع الاجراء المطلوب}

\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=white,radiosymbol=\ding{53},borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30]{اصدار وثيقة}
\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=white,radiosymbol=\ding{53},borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30]{تعديل وثيقة}
\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=white,radiosymbol=\ding{53},borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30]{حذف وثيقة}


\end{Form}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex               
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

**Output**
[image: output]

As you can see the text boxes are not aligned well with text and actually not even placed as intended. Some text is hidden by the check-boxes, so how to get such forms right in this case? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to update [`bidi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package, but I think it remains the problem of writing arabic within Text Fields

Comment: I updated `bibi` pkg to v35.4, and there was an improvement in the layout but checkboxes are still hiding some of the preceding text.

Comment: Try to change the layout of check field with `\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{#1\hskip1.3em #2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a recent version of `bidi` package which adapt a lot of packages for right to left writing, package `polyglossia` uses implicitly  `bidi`  for  languages with right to left script.

Second for `CheckBox` the command `\LayoutCheckField` can be used to change check field layout

```
\documentclass[a4,pagesize=pdftex,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=mashriq,numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}
% User-defined commands
\newcommand{\AR}{\textarabic}
\newcommand{\EN}{\textenglish}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\centering
 \LARGE\textbf{استمارة باللغة العربية}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vskip 1cm

\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,maxlen=30,width=0.5\textwidth]{اسم الوثيقة:} 

\TextField[mappingname=title,name=title,backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,width=0.5\textwidth,multiline]{تعليق:}

 \LARGE\textbf{نوع الاجراء المطلوب}

\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 \hskip1.3em #2%
}


\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=white,radiosymbol=\ding{53},borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30]{اصدار وثيقة}
\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=white,radiosymbol=\ding{53},borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30]{تعديل وثيقة}
\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=white,radiosymbol=\ding{53},borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30]{حذف وثيقة}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]